# Ajax form uses name field data in success message when in JSFIDDLE but doesn't work on my site

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am using a form that displays a success message with the person's name, which is achieved by using the data filled in the name input field of my form.

The form is successful when viewing within JSFIDDLE, which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/224e2zmp/).

But when using the code exactly as is on my site, the success message says:
"Hi Undefined" instead of "Hi John Appleseed", for example.

How do I get the success message to display the input data from the first field in my form?

Thanks.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var errors = false;
  $('.required').parent().find('.input').on('blur', function() {
    var error_div = $(this).parent().find('.error_message');
    var field_container = $(this).parent();
    if (!$.empty_field_validation($(this).val())) {
      error_div.html('This field is required.');
      error_div.css('display', 'block');
      field_container.addClass('error');
      errors = true;
    } else {
      error_div.html('');
      error_div.css('display', 'none');
      field_container.removeClass('error');
      errors = false;
    }
  });
  $('#email').on('blur', function() {
    var error_div = $(this).parent().find('.error_message');
    var field_container = $(this).parent();
    if (!$.email_validation($(this).val())) {
      error_div.html('Expected Input: email');
      error_div.css('display', 'block');
      field_container.addClass('error');
      errors = true;
    } else {
      error_div.html('');
      error_div.css('display', 'none');
      field_container.removeClass('error');
      errors = false;
    }
  });
  $('#message').on('blur', function() {
    var error_div = $(this).parent().find('.error_message');
    var field_container = $(this).parent();
    if (!$.empty_field_validation($(this).val())) {
      error_div.html('Expected Input: message');
      error_div.css('display', 'block');
      field_container.addClass('error');
      errors = true;
    } else {
      error_div.html('');
      error_div.css('display', 'none');
      field_container.removeClass('error');
      errors = false;
    }
  });
  $('#contact_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.required').parent().find('.input').trigger('blur');
    if (!errors)
      $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
          json: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject())
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
          var message = 'Hi ' + data.name + '. Your message was sent and received.';
          $('#after_submit').html(message);
          $('#after_submit').css('display', 'block');
        },
        error: function() {
          var message = 'Hi ' + data.name + '. Your message could not be sent or received. Please try again later';
          $('#after_submit').html(message);
          $('#after_submit').css('display', 'block');
        }
      });
    else
      alert("You didn't completed the form correctly. Check it out and try again!");
  });
});

$.empty_field_validation = function(field_value) {
  if (field_value.trim() == '') return false;
  return true;
}

$.email_validation = function(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var o = {};
  var a = this.serializeArray();
  $.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name]) {
      if (!o[this.name].push) {
        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
      }
      o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
      o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
  });
  return o;
};
```

**FORM**

```
<div id="after_submit"></div>
<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="required" for="name">Your name:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" />
    <br />
    <span id="name_validation" class="error_message"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="required" for="email">Your email:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" />
    <br />
    <span id="email_validation" class="error_message"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="required" for="message">Your message:</label>
    <br />
    <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
    <br />
    <span id="message_validation" class="error_message"></span>
  </div>

  <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  width: 414px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#after_submit,
#email_validation,
#name_validation {
  display: none;
}

#after_submit {
  background-color: #c0ffc0;
  line-height: 31px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

label,
#after_submit {
  color: #6c6c6c;
}

input {
  line-height: 31px;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 288px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  border: solid 1px #b6c7cb;
}

#contact_form {
  height: 317px;
  background-color: #e1e9eb;
  border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
  padding: 10px 20px 50px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#submit_button {
  width: 109px;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #86c5fa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .29);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .29);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .29);
  border: solid 1px #77a4cb;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

label.required:after {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
}

.error {
  background-color: #FFDFDF;
  color: red;
}

.error_message {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: When you make the request to your own site, what is the response?  What's in `data`?

Comment: The data is supposed to be what the user has input into the 'name' (first) form field.

Comment: That's nice, but that doesn't appear to be the cast.  Don't assume that it should work, debug to see what's wrong.

Comment: It says it is undefined and I am confused as to how I should define it. I thought it was correct.

Comment: Check your browser's debugging tools to see what's actually being returned from the server.  If your server-side code isn't returning the value then the value won't be there.

Comment: Also, in the `error()` function there *is no* `data` variable, so it's definitely going to be undefined there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function:

```
success: function(data) {
      var message = 'Hi ' + data.name + '. Your message was sent and received.';
      //...
}
```

If `data.name` is `undefined` then that means whatever the server returned doesn't have a `name` property.  (If the server returned any valid JSON object at all.)  You're going to have to debug and see what the server *does* return.  And check your server-side code (which you don't show here) to see what's going on.

---

In this function:

```
error: function() {
    var message = 'Hi ' + data.name + '. Your message could not be sent or received. Please try again later';
    //...
}
```

There *is no* `data` variable defined in the function.  So `data` itself is `undefined`.  I'm not really sure what you expect `data.name` to contain here, or where you think it's coming from, but since you never defined it then it doesn't exist.

Comment: Then how would I go about defining it? All I want it to say is the person's name, the name field they fill out?

Comment: @roxy-p: You'd define it by, well, defining the variable in some way.  Just like any other variable.  If all you want is to show the value that's been entered, why involve server-side code at all?  `$('#name').val()` would get the value from the `input`.

Comment: As naive as this may sound, do I add it to my jquery and then leave the data.name to call to it to display that input?

Comment: @roxy-p: That question doesn't make much sense to me.  I suspect you're experiencing some fundamental misunderstandings here.  Basically, in order for the `data` variable to exist, it has to be defined somewhere.  The `success()` function defines it as an argument to the function.  In order for the `data` property on that variable to exist, *it also* has to be defined somewhere.  The `success()` function is assuming that the server returns it.  However, if all you need is the value from that `input`, then you don't need to ask the server to return it since you already have it.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate the explanation! What I was asking was how do I write that. I understand the explanation, I just don't know how to implement it into what I have already. I'm not that clued up on how it works.

Comment: @roxy-p: Basically, in your callback functions try using `$('#name').val()` instead of `data.name`.  Since the latter isn't defined anywhere, just get the value directly from the former.  (Unless there's some compelling reason why this value needs to come from server-side code, perhaps if that code is validating or modifying it in any way?)

Comment: I could honestly not thank you more! That worked perfectly. I am using a validation but this is not dependent on it.